# Django generic views extra context

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the generic DetailView and add some context there to use in a template.

My view looks like

```
class SpecsView(DetailView):
    model = Specification

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SpecsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pretty_json = "So pretty so pretty"
        context['pretty_json'] = pretty_json
        context['hello'] = "Hellow hellow"
        return context
```

As you can see I added two fields before returning the context, as per the tutorial / doc in Django.

In my template, I have (fraction)

```
    <p> Specs should come here.</p>
    {{ specification.pretty_json }}
    {{ specification.hello }}
    <p> No further.</p>
```

Everything else works, i.e. I can use and display any other fields of my model Specification.

But nothing displays when I use the extended context.

HTML result -->

```
Specs should come here.

No further.
```

Hopefully I am missing something obvious.
I am using Python 3.4, django 1.8.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding `pretty_json` and `hello` directly in context, so to call them use:

```
{{ pretty_json }}
{{ hello }}
```

Comment: Duh... Yes, that fixes it! Thanks for the super fast answer!

Comment: How would I do to replace the dummy value with some manipulation of a field of my current object being detailed?

Comment: @CedricDruck If you need this values (`pretty_json` and `hello`) to be part of the current object, you could define them in the model as properties with `@property` decorator.